# Is sorting broken?

Tags: bug

If I sort the questions by vote, and ask to get the questions with not accepted answer, [I get](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=MostVotes&filters=NoAcceptedAnswer):

[image]

However, [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/214273/101324) (that I happened to ask) has 30 votes and no accepted answer.

Why is it not showing up?

Comment: Since this is general SE functionality, you might need to ask/answer on the main Meta somewhere near https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327816/307535

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks, I migrated it to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337459/262759